# Jquery Image Source Change is not Working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am Trying to change user image through ajax by overwriting existing image file with new one so how can i show user image without reloading the page.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // $("#message").empty();
        // $('#loading').show();
        alert('i m clicked');
        $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
        // $('#loading').hide();
        $('#previewing').hide();
        // $("#message").html(data);
        // $('PreviewImage').attr("src","<?php echo $ImageSource; ?>");
        var img = $("#PreviewImage");
        img.attr("src","<?php echo $ImageSource; ?>");
        // alert(data);
    }
    });
}));
```

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor Send the image back from PHP in base64 format.

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor you use response instead of data on the success callback function

Comment: `img.attr("src","<?php echo $ImageSource; ?>");`  you are using previous path only, you should return new image path in `data` and on success you should use the new path. and why r u using location.reload? if you dont want to reload the page

Comment: What is the response you are getting from the AJAX call? Also, please use `data` from response.

Comment: Ash my new path is same as old path because i am overwriting new image with old one and path will remain same

Comment: if your image is not getting refreshed add time string after image url like $timestamp = time(); img.attr("src","<?php echo $ImageSource.'?'.$timestamp;");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Deepak comment i have concatenate the `timestamp` with image `source` to show new image.

> if your image is not getting refreshed add time string after image url like
> `$timestamp = time();  img.attr("src","<?php echo $ImageSource.'?'.$timestamp;");`